# Reading a text file into a 2D array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, file

I am trying to extract data from a text file and place it into a 2D array where the columns are organized by what value they represent so I can plot the data and analyze it. The data in the text file is formatted like

> 10.24284  49.89447    462.90  312.4   Wed Dec 7, 2016 6:42:10p EST

I want to be able to separate the values in each column into their own lists or a full 2D array. I have tried looking into `open('filename')` as well as `readlines` but it just returns a mess of numbers that are not sorted in any way. What is the best solution to the problem?

Comment: Is your input file well-structured? You could try using a CSV format for the input file to make it easier to extract the columns for each entry line.

Comment: Split each line, and store those arrays into an array => 2D array?

Answer (score 2):

Using `open('filename', 'r')` (the r means read) you can loop over all the lines in the code with a simple for loop. something like this:

```
with open('filename', 'r') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        #do something with the string
```

You said that the data you had was formatted like this:

> 10.24284 49.89447 462.90 312.4 Wed Dec 7, 2016 6:42:10p EST

you could take each line and split it on every space like this:

```
line.split(" ")
```

you would now have something like:

```
['10.24284', '49.89447', '462.90', '312.4', 'Wed', 'Dec', '7,', '2016', '6:42:10p', 'EST']
```

if you wanted to keep the date together in the final array you could limit how many time you split it like this:

```
 line.split(" ", 4)
```

this would give you:

```
['10.24284', '49.89447', '462.90', '312.4', 'Wed Dec 7, 2016 6:42:10p EST']
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers part is trivial...

```
result = [map(float, L.split()[:4]) for L in open("datafile.txt")]
```

`result[43][2]` will be the third number on 44-th row (counting starts from 0 in Python)